# Apache Poi the Excel(.xlsx) file is corrupted. (Using XSSF)

Tags: java, spring, amazon-ec2, apache-poi

I am working with [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) and I create an XSSF workbook and try to open an xlsx file. it works well in a  local.  But the Excel file from the real server(AWS EC2, Tomcat8, JDK 1.8) when I open with excel, it says the file is corrupted (.xls works). Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.document.AbstractXlsxView;

protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Workbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<BoardArticleDto> list = (List<BoardArticleDto>)model.get("data");
        String filename = HttpUtils.uriEncoding("문의내역리스트.xlsx", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");  
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\";");
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

        int cnt = 0, rowNum = 0;

        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();    
        Sheet sheet  = wb.createSheet("문의내역리스트");

        Row row = null;
        row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);

        row.createCell(cnt++).setCellValue( "유형" );
        sheet.setColumnWidth(cnt, 30 * 256);
        row.createCell(cnt++).setCellValue( "첨부파일" );
        sheet.setColumnWidth(cnt, 40 * 256);
        row.createCell(cnt++).setCellValue( "제목" );
        sheet.setColumnWidth(cnt, 20 * 256);
        row.createCell(cnt++).setCellValue( "작성자" );
        sheet.setColumnWidth(cnt, 26 * 256);
        row.createCell(cnt++).setCellValue( "등록일자" );
        row.createCell(cnt++).setCellValue( "답변여부" );

        int rownum = 1;

        if( null != list ){
            for( BoardArticleDto bda : list ){

                cnt = 0;
                row = sheet.createRow(rownum);

                row.createCell(cnt++).setCellValue( Converter.toStr(bda.getCSC_NAME1()) );
                row.createCell(cnt++).setCellValue( Converter.toStr(bda.getBDA_FILE1()) );
                row.createCell(cnt++).setCellValue( Converter.toStr(bda.getBDA_NAME()) );
                row.createCell(cnt++).setCellValue( Converter.toStr(bda.getMB_NAME()) );
                row.createCell(cnt++).setCellValue( Converter.toStr(bda.getBDA_INDATE()).substring(0, 10) );
                row.createCell(cnt++).setCellValue( Converter.toStr(bda.getBDA_REPLYYN()) );

                rownum++;
            }

        }

        OutputStream fileOut = response.getOutputStream();
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }

}
```

**Local**
Spring4, jdk1.8, tomcat 8.0, maven

**Real**
AWS EC2 Amazon linux2, jdk1.8, tomcat 8.0 (without Apache Webserver)

[Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) version 3.10.1

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the whole code,
But i recommend to check this `response.getOutputStream()`
Debug and see what does this return, if the value is not what you want, check out what could be wrong with your response.

If it is correct, try creating a simple file with normal Characters (not Korean)
If you don't have a problem with creating this, then it is an encoding problem.
And throught this way you can find the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will solve your problem, but always `wb.close()` your workbook when you don't need it anymore.